# vim-airline not displayed correctly

Tags: vim

My `vim-airline` plugin looks like this:
[image]

But on all screenshots it might be like this:
[image]

Here my Vundle plugins list:

```
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'rking/ag.vim'
Plugin 'skwp/greplace.vim'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'StanAngeloff/php.vim'
Plugin 'arnaud-lb/vim-php-namespace'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'stephpy/vim-php-cs-fixer'
Plugin 'tobyS/vmustache'
Plugin 'tobyS/pdv'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
```

Some config from my `.vimrc` file, without plugins config:

```
set nocompatible

syntax enable
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set number
let mapleader = ',' 
set noerrorbells visualbell t_vb=           
set autowriteall                    
set complete=.,w,b,u                    
set tabstop=8
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

"------------Visuals-------------"
set background=dark
colorscheme material-theme
set t_CO=256                
set guifont=Operator\Mono\ weight=350\ 10
set linespace=10
set guioptions-=e           

set guioptions-=l           
set guioptions-=L
set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=R

hi LineNr guibg=bg
set foldcolumn=2
hi foldcolumn guibg=bg

hi vertsplit guifg=bg guibg=bg
```

I using Ubuntu 16.04, try to use gVim and terminal vim, the same.

I try to comment all visual config like theme, guifonr, but the same result.

Comment: I heard that those *-lines need some font patch. have you done this step?

Comment: @Kent yes, that`s was a problem, I didn`t find my font Operator there, but it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I install [powerline/fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) (thanks @Kent) and after commands:

```
# clone
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git
# install
cd fonts
./install.sh
# clean-up a bit
cd ..
rm -rf fonts
```

My status looks like better, but not ideal, I think it`s because I didn`t find my font in that repository, but it`s nit big problem.

Now my panel look like this:
[image: sample]